# Access SharePoint Online via CSOM with access Token from Username/Password in Azure Functions

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, error, azure-functions

I want to access a SharePoint site with a Token, which I get by Username and PW (`AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword`). I get the Token and I can access the site via Postman without any problems, but in my code is an error.

Can you help me to find the error?

Here is my code so far:

```
    else
            {
                try
                {


                    var securePassword = new SecureString();

                    foreach (char c in {Password})
                    {
                        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                    }


                    result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, "manager@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com", securePassword)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    var tokenSP = result.AccessToken;
                     var AccountName =   result.Account;


                    log.LogInformation($"Token : {tokenSP} {AccountName}");

                    var siteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TestGetfolder";

                    try
                    {
                        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
                        
                        

                        clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            args.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authoritzation"] = "Bearer " + tokenSP;

                        };

                        

                        var web = clientContext.Web;

                        clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Title);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                        log.LogInformation(web.Title);

                        

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation(e.ToString());

                    }




                }
                catch (MsalException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result.Account.Username);




            return new OkObjectResult("End");
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm executing the code, I get the following error message:

[image: Problem with Token]

Comment: I solved the problem. I used the wrong Nuget Package. I needed to use the following: Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM Version 16.1.23408.12000

Answer (score 0):

Header name "Authoritzation" should be "Authorization"